# Jackson json only convert selected fields and methods

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jackson-databind

With jackson there is a way to ignore some fields using `@JsonIgnore`. Is there a way to do the opposite, and only show fields with are annotated? I'm working with an external class with *a lot* of fields and I only want to select a small subset of them. I'm getting tons of recursion problems (using some type of ORM) where object A -> B -> A -> B -> A .... which are not even necessary to export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the object mapper to ignore absolutely everything unless specified by `JsonProperty`,

```
public class JacksonConfig {
    
    public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(){
    //The marshaller
    ObjectMapper marshaller = new ObjectMapper();

    //Make it ignore all fields unless we specify them
    marshaller.setVisibility(
        new VisibilityChecker.Std(
            JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE
        )
    );

    //Allow empty objects
    marshaller.configure( SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false );

    return marshaller;
    
    }
}
```

```
public class MyObject {

    private int id;
    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
    private Date date;

//Getters Setters omitted
```

in this case only `name` would be serialized.

Sample repo, https://github.com/DarrenForsythe/jackson-ignore-everything

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely you can; Create a class with only the feilds you need  and add the below property in the object mapper and rest is done.

```
DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)** on the pojo class so only the fields which are available in the pojo class will be mapped and resf will be left out.

**For example**

**Json data**

```
{
"name":"Abhishek",
"age":30,
"city":"Banglore",
"state":"Karnatak"
}
```

**pojo class**

```
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
Class Person{
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String city;
}
```

Here state in not present in the Person class so that field won't be mapped